When can a R matrix be brought to Hermitian form?
For this question, let "R matrix" denote a (preferrably invertible) solution of the (constant) Yang Baxter equation. Any R matrix (if you alternatively write it as tensor $R^{ab}_{cd}$) is gauge invariant under $R'=(T\bigotimes T)R(T\bigotimes T)^{-1}$ (with some invertible transformation matrix $T$), and the question is now whether this gauge can be used to bring a specific $R$ to Hermitian form.
I think the answer is "yes" for any R matrix which describes some irrep of a quantum Lie algebra which is semisimple and the irrep real.
A definite no to some of Hietarinta's $4\times4$ list (even if constraining to the $11$ invertible ones), as some are "Jordan" and thus can't be diagonalized (maybe some describe some irrep of a non-semisimple Lie algebra...).
Questions

What about a complex irrep of a quantum semisimple Lie algebra, say the $\dim=3$ irrep of $A_2$?
Can that $9\times 9$ matrix be brought to Hermitian form with a proper basis? (The physicists should know, since Hermitian is connected to time-reversal invariance.) I suspect "semisimple" is sufficient for Hermitian. (But not necessary - direct product of semisimple and abelian seems to work too. On the other hand, I suspect Hietarinta's "upper diagonal" solution H2.3 is connected to the Lie algebra $aff(1)$.)


Is part of the question missing? You talk about the answer being yes or no, but the answer to what? Brought to Hermitian form how?
